# Slickgrid custom sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, slickgrid

I am trying to implement a custom sorting in slick grid.  I am using this as a reference https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#sorting.  I want to force rows with specific properties to always sort to the bottom of the grid.  (I tried to get a working example of slickgrid to work in jsfiddle.net but I couldn't.) I have tried this but it's not working.

```
var gridData =[
    { Id:1, Code: '232046', Depth2: 4000,},
    { Id:2, Code: '23247', Depth2: 2000 },
    { Id:3, Code: '12543', Depth2: 1500, rowoption_stickyorder: 1 }
];

grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    var footerOrderProperty = 'rowoption_stickyorder';

    var comparer = function (a, b) {
      var result = (a[args.sortCol.field] > b[args.sortCol.field]) ? 1 : -1;

      if (b[footerOrderProperty] != undefined || a[footerOrderProperty] != undefined)
          result = -1;

       return result;
    }
    dataview.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (b[footerOrderProperty] != undefined || a[footerOrderProperty] != undefined)
   result = -1;
```

Won't work. `false || true` places an object/row with the property above one that does not have it.

```
var bb = b[footerOrderProperty],
    aa = a[footerOrderProperty];

if(aa && !bb){
   result = 1;
}
else if(!aa && bb)
{
  result = -1
}
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/9Bydm/)

Note: Fiddle won't work in Chrome due to the mime type issue and the common workaround of making the resource `rawgithub` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You rock!  Now that you pointed it out I see my problem.  Crazy I could only get the Fiddle to work in firefox. (Chrome and IE11 didn't work.)

Comment: http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/ explains the Chrome issue. I have had it working in the past, but it wouldn't this time around for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Origineil, great work!  Your suggestion got me 99% of the way there.  I really want to have the columns sortable in both directions and keep the rows at the bottom.  I modified your code to take in account the sortOrder and it works like a champ.

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    console.log(args.sortAsc)
    var footerOrderProperty = 'rowoption_stickyorder';
    var comparer = function (a, b) {
      var result = (a[args.sortCol.field] > b[args.sortCol.field]) ? 1 : -1;

      var bb = b[footerOrderProperty],
          aa = a[footerOrderProperty];

      if (aa && !bb) {
          result = args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1;
      } else if (!aa && bb) {
          result = args.sortAsc ? -1 : 1;
      } else if (aa != undefined && bb != undefined) {
           result = (aa > bb) ? 1 : -1;
           result *= args.sortAsc ? 1 : -1
      }

      console.log(a.id + " | " + b.id + " " + result)
      return result
   }

  dataView.sort(comparer, args.sortAsc);
});
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Bydm/10).

Comment: Careful on that last `else if`, the `bb[footerOrderProperty]` should be either just `bb` or `b[footerOrderProperty]`

Comment: yeah, I just caught that too. I fixed both the fiddle and the response.  Thanks again for your help!